# Jenkins webook failed in Bitbucket but work fine with curl

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, webhooks, bitbucket-webhook

I am working to create webhook which any git push from Bitbucket will trigger Jenkin job to run on a Linux host (without plugin).

In jenkins, I created a simple pipeline, and came up with this webhook URL.
`http://admin:apiToken@www.myjenkins.com:8080/job/job123/build?token=xxxxxx`
I tested to run this webhook URL on CLI, it worked and I could see new job fired up successfully in Jenkins Portal.

```
$ curl -s --show-error http://admin:apiToken@www.myjenkins.com:8080/job/job123/build?token=xxxxxx
```

However, this URL is NOT working in Bitbucket's webhook setting (project > repo > repo settings > webhooks ) . I clicked 'test connection' it returned `403` with the following error response

```
Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:
  
Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->
```

I used `admin` account but it said 'anonymous`.

I also tested `git push` and nothing happened in Jenkins.
According to the error response, Looks like it related to authentication issue... but it was weird, command line with `curl` was working fine. That means:

- authentication with admin token is fine.
- resource URL is correct.

But the same doesn't work in Bitbucket.

Finally, I tested to enable anonymous account in Jenkins, the Bitbucket could trigger build to Jenkins but too risky.
Does anyone have idea on my problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what source control plugin you are using in Jenkins, there are several ways of achieving your goal:

1. Bitbucket Server Integration plugin (https://plugins.jenkins.io/atlassian-bitbucket-server-integration/)
   After configuring it in the main Jenkins configuration page
   [image: Jenkins main configuration page]

(following the guides), you could select from Jenkins job - > Bitbucket server trigger build after push [image]

which will create a Webhook in Bitbucket repo automatically when applied/saved in Jenkins
[image]

2. Git plugin (https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/)
   In the Job configuration page, you could select "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket"

[image]

which will work only after someone with admin rights to the repository creates the webhook manually with the following URL "`{FULL_JENKINS_URL}/bitbucket-hook/`"